# Run-time error 1004: This action won't work on multiple selections

Tags: excel, vba

**First of all I need to inform you that I don't know how to program at all.** I found this code online. It was working for what I needed it to do, now it is giving me the run-time error 1004.

What I need this code to do is add a row and keep the equations that are in the previous rows.

I don't know what to do to troubleshoot this error. As I've mentioned I don't have a programming background. I'm hoping that I don't get put down because I don't know what I'm doing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160725
Cancel = True
Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
On Error Resume Next
Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
End Sub
```

The line that is Highlighted is: "Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow"

The following are the formulas that are in the columns that need to be added to the next row when I double click.

Starting from column N through column AB.

```
Column N
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Avox Production",$B$3:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column O
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Avox Packaging",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column P
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cuvette Production",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column Q
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cuvette Packaging",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column R
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Incision Production",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column S
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Incision Packaging",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column T
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Instrument Production",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column U
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Instrument Packaging",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column V
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Instrument Service",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column W
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("R & D",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column X
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Reagent Lab",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column Y
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Tubes",$B$207:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column Z
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Verify Now",$B$3:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column AA
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Finished Goods",$B$3:$B$3590)),"1","")

Column AB
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Warehouse",$B$3:$B$3590)),"1","")
```

This code was working fine for about 5 weeks. I don't know if someone accidentally did something that is causing the code to not work.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, or, at least reasonably clear by Microsoft standards. Some things simply can't be done on non-contiguous selections. It seems like that's what's happening here. Which line raises the error?

Comment: FWIW, I'm not able to reproduce this error. Even tried adding some merged cells/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got actually the same problem. For me I'm pretty sure it's because I am hiding some of the columns, and that the code doesn't like that. I also use custom views, which might have to do something with it.

When I unhide all the columns the Code does work find. Haven't found a way to use it without error message when hiding some columns.